# Keras deep learning model always give same acc in training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to make a prediction with Keras. But it gives always same acc value in training. But loss is decrasing while in training

I'm trying to predict production parameters. Some examples are given below

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBK5e.png)

So i want to basically predict fill_press parameter from others. My code is here:

```
x = pd.concat([volume, injector, filling_time, machine], axis=1)


x_train, x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=1)



predicter = Sequential()

predicter.add(Dense(units=9, use_bias = True,  kernel_initializer = 'RandomUniform', activation = 'linear', input_dim = 9)) #Input Layer

predicter.add(Dense(units=7, use_bias = True,  kernel_initializer = 'RandomUniform', activation = 'linear'))

predicter.add(Dense(units=4, use_bias = True,  kernel_initializer = 'RandomUniform', activation = 'linear'))

predicter.add(Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer = 'RandomUniform', activation = 'linear'))

predicter.compile(optimizer = "sgd", loss = 'mean_absolute_error', metrics = ['accuracy'])

predicter.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size =10, epochs = 1000)



y_pred = predicter.predict(X_test)
```

What should i change? Also i'm not sure my model is correct. Do you have any recommendation?

As you can see acc always same(0.1333) from start to end.

***Also i should highlight that, i have quite low number of data.***

Training output:

```
Epoch 985/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 337us/step - loss: 0.0990 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 986/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 289us/step - loss: 0.1006 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 987/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 266us/step - loss: 0.1003 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 988/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 355us/step - loss: 0.0997 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 989/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 199us/step - loss: 0.1003 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 990/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 167us/step - loss: 0.1001 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 991/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 200us/step - loss: 0.0997 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 992/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 222us/step - loss: 0.0987 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 993/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 304us/step - loss: 0.0984 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 994/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 244us/step - loss: 0.1001 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 995/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 332us/step - loss: 0.1006 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 996/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 356us/step - loss: 0.0999 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 997/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 332us/step - loss: 0.1014 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 998/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 394us/step - loss: 0.0988 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 999/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 269us/step - loss: 0.1013 - acc: 0.1333
Epoch 1000/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 242us/step - loss: 0.0992 - acc: 0.1333
```

Comment: What is the data for y? It is not clear if your problem is a classification problem or not. If it is not classification, how do you interpret accuracy and why do you want to track it? Also, is there any specific reason why you use linear activation function? It may not be the best choice, as it makes the model essentially a linear regression.

Comment: The data for y is press_fill, there is no spesific reason for using linear activation function. I think you are right linear activation model is not the right choice. Do you have any further recommendation for model?

Comment: What is press_fill? Please don't assume that we know your code or task, you have to tell us about that. To me it sounds like you are doing regression, not classification, correct?

Comment: Hi Matias, The task is that, i want to predict plastic injection production parameters and press_fill mean is pressure of filling that depends on part volume, filling time, machine type(1800 is a machine type not number) and injector number of mold. For example: if part volume: 10, injector: 5, fill_time: 3 what should it pressure of filling in machine type 1800? I hope i explain it well and thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I guess since you have on output unit and a linear activation function for your last dense layer, you are performing regression.

However, accuracy in tensorflow is meant to be used for classification tasks. See the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy.